# Turn array of HTML Strings into an array of HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, dom

I have an array of HTML strings:

```
["<h1>this is a title</h1>", "<a href=#>link</a>", "<img src="#" />","<p>a long paragraph</p>"]
```

How would I convert these into an array of HTML tags, I'm ultimately trying to return the array to render in React.

I've tried using:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/xml");
```

but that creates an array of `doument`s.  Obviously I can't use innerHTML because of the `img` and `a href` tags.

Comment: just join array elements together as a string like this: ```new DOMParser().parseFromString(youArray.join(','), "text/xml")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) method to parse XML/HTML string, here is a working snippet:

```js
let elements = ["<h1>this is a title</h1>", "<a href=#>link</a>", "<img src='#' />","<p>a long paragraph</p>"];

let container = document.getElementById('container');

elements.forEach((el, i) => {
  const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(el);
  console.log(fragment.children[0]);
  container.appendChild(fragment.children[0]);
})
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) on each element to get the tags like:

```js
const data = ["<h1>this is a title</h1>", "<a href=#>link</a>", "<img src='#' />", "<p>a long paragraph</p>"]
const res = data.map(tag => new DOMParser()
  .parseFromString(tag, "text/html")
  .querySelectorAll("*:not(html):not(head):not(body)")[0])

console.log(res)
```